# While Loop Of Large Dataset Printing Incorrect Results

Tags: r, while-loop

I'm working with a large dataset of 2132 values that contains two columns, one indicating the start date of a customer, and the other indicating the end date.

I am currently using a while loop to iterate through my dataset. If the end date of a customer is NA it adds 'NA' to a vector s. If the end date is greater than the start date, it subtracts the two and adds that number to s. Finally, if the start date and end date are equal, it adds a 1 to vector s.

The first couple values I should have in vector s are: NA, 1,1,NA,2,1,2.

Yet, my while loop is currently returning: 1, NA, 1, 1, NA,1,1.

What is wrong in my while loop logic?

The first couple values of my dataset are:

```
a(first)  b(last)
2         NA
3         3
3         3
4         NA
4         5
2         2
2         3
```

My code is as follows:

```
x <- 1
while (x <= 2132)
{
  if (is.na(b[x])) 
  {
     s <- c(s,'NA')
  }
  else if(a[x] < b[x])
  {
     s <- c(s,(b[x] - a[x]) + 1)
  }
  else if (a[x] == b[x])
  {
     s <- c(s,1)
  }
  x = x + 1
}
```

Comment: Assuming you initialise `s` to an empty `numeric` or `character`, the loop yield  an `s` value of `[1] NA  1  1 NA  2  1  2` (with `x <= length(b)`)

Comment: Forgot to initialize s to an empty vector. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a `for` or `while` loop here. A core tenant of R programming is the concept of vectorization.

In short, you can implement all of your logic at once. For this, I would use two `ifelse()` functions:

```r
d <- data.frame(a = c(2,3,3,4,4,2,2), b = c(NA, 3,3,NA,5,2,3))
d$s <- with(d, ifelse(is.na(b), NA, ifelse(b > a, b -a + 1, 1)))
d
#>   a  b  s
#> 1 2 NA NA
#> 2 3  3  1
#> 3 3  3  1
#> 4 4 NA NA
#> 5 4  5  2
#> 6 2  2  1
#> 7 2  3  2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>